# Dynamically access an array using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to access different arrays based on the users choice and then run through the array with a ng-repeat.

Controller:

```
$scope.allbooks={
book1:{price:"3.00",type:"non-fiction",chapters:book1chapters},
book2:{price:"4.00",type:"fiction",chapters:book2chapters},
};

$scope.pick = function(selectedBook) {
    $rootScope.choice = selectedBook;
  }

$scope.book1chapters=[
{title:"it begins"},
{title:"another one"}
];

$scope.book2chapters=[
{title:"hello"},
{title:"calling from the otherside"}
];
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="pick(allbooks.book1)">Book 1</button>
<button ng-click="pick(allbooks.book2)">Book 2</button>

<div ng-repeat:"m in choice.chapters"><-----this does not work
Chapter: {{m.title}}
</div>
```

This is a very simplified example just to make it easier to look at :) I don't know how t reference another array from inside an array. Thanks

Comment: what's error you got?

Comment: no errors...{{m.title}} does just not show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you did not define `book1chapters` and `book1chapters` for collection `allbooks`, instead you defined them in `$scope` which is not correct. Also change `$rootScope` to `$scope` since `rootScope` is not injected. The following code is working:

```
var book1chapters = [{
  title: "it begins"
}, {
  title: "another one"
}];

var book2chapters = [{
  title: "hello"
}, {
  title: "calling from the otherside"
}];

 $scope.allbooks = {
  book1: {
    price: "3.00",
    type: "non-fiction",
    chapters: book1chapters
  },
  book2: {
    price: "4.00",
    type: "fiction",
    chapters: book2chapters
  },
};

$scope.pick = function(selectedBook) {
  $scope.choice = selectedBook;
}
```

The code on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/83Ujp4R8BjIe39ROmp6n?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer

Basically you have incorrect `ng-repeat` syntax. It should have `=` instead of  `:` before writing expression in front of `ng-repeat` directive like we do for `value` attribute

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="m in choice.chapters"><-----this does not work
   Chapter: {{m.title}}
</div>
```

**Suggestions**

You should not pollute `$rootScope` for sharing variables. For that you could create a shareable service which can share a data among-est various components of your app like controllers, directives, service, etc.

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="sharableData.choice = 'book1'">Book 1</button>
<button ng-click="sharableData.choice = 'book2'">Book 2</button>

<div ng-repeat = "m in allbooks[sharableData.choice].chapters">
   Chapter: {{m.title}}
</div>
```

**Service**

```
app.service('sharableData', function(){
  var sharableData = this;
  sharableData.sharedData = {
     choice: undefined
  };
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, sharableData){
   //you other controller code
   //add this additional line to expose service variable on html
   $scope.sharableData = sharableData;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I typed the example to fast and missed the "=" sign, I do have that in my original code. Also, I do have to share the choice variables to multiple controllers, thats why I used $rootScope....do you know how it can be done using choice variable

Comment: Yes..you need to create one service which can share data amongest several controllers(components)..

Comment: Ok, but how do I use the choice variable in the ng-repeat.... m in choice.chapters does not work

Comment: @MehdiN the question could be solved by simply having `<div ng-repeat="m in choice.chapters"><-----this does not work
Chapter: {{m.title}}
</div>`

Comment: I don't understand...thats what I have right now and it does not work...I have the =

Comment: @MehdiN it should work,  though lets try the other part of my answer..which I wrote in suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions ..but can we do it just with $rootScope as I feel the services would cause additional problems for me (new to coding)...do you see any issues with the way I formatted the array or objects in the array

Comment: No..it wouldn't cause any issue..using $rootScope is not good pattern to follow.. No there isn't any issue issue eith array structure

Comment: Ok. I will try your solution again and maybe on a new page with its own controller..Thanks :)

Comment: I found the issue (I hope)...in my array I can not set "chapters:book1chapters" without causing crash...it only allows me to set "chapters: "book1chapters"" in quotes...do you have any solution?

Comment: so isn't that setting chapters to a string instead of the array

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying..do upvote if it does helped.